# Generate HUGE Json file with PHP & SQL

Tags: php, sql, json, sqlsrv

I am trying to create a json file with PHP & SQL Server.

I tried with this code:

```
$fp = fopen('file.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($return_arr));
fclose($fp);
```

But there is a Limit in fwrite function.

I tried by changing my code to:

```
$fp   = fopen("file.json", "w");

$pieces = str_split($return_arr, 1024 * 4); //Also change values here as 2048 * 4 and 2048*20
foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
    fwrite($fp, $piece, strlen($piece));
}

fclose($file);
```

and split it But still no chance.

Also I changed memory limit that `ini_set('memory_limit','248M');` and on `php.ini` file, but still not working.

**EDIT**

Also I tried that but still not working

```
$fp = fopen('file.json', 'w');
file_put_contents($fp,json_encode($return_arr));
fclose($fp);
```

My file is generated up to 1500 records. After that I get nothing back. If I increase the `SELECT TOP 1500` to `SELECT TOP 2000` my json file is empty.

I really need some help.. Any feedback on how can that be solved?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `file_put_contents()`?

Comment: yes I did i forgot to mention that but I am not sure if I use it properly. Can you please take a look at the updated question? Thanks

Comment: No not like this, write it like this `file_put_contents("file.json", json_encode($return_arr));` without using fopen and fclose

Comment: 1500 isn't that big maybe you have an error somewhere not related to just file size that. Make sure to enable all errors and warning and reload the page until it stops loading and see what it says. Then paste back what the error(s) are if you can't determine how to fix it still. Did you try increasing the memory limit and what about max execution time?

Comment: @Danny a lot depends on record size, it may be huge by itself

Comment: @Danny I have my errors on but I get no error back

Comment: What about echo'ing out the contents to the browser instead of writing to the file does that work without errors?

Comment: @Maria if your results set is plain array and it is being fetched from database - what about writing start `[` then encode and write each item separately and then write final `]`? It will save memory significantly

Comment: @Danny if I add print_r($return_arr) I can display everything with no error. But js file is empty. If I reduce it to 1500 from SQL i get this on screen and on file as well

Comment: Try what @Flying mentioned change your SQL to read one line at a time and write it to the file before moving onto the next line instead of putting all the results into an array then looping/writing from that.

Comment: What about `file_put_contents()` did it work?

Comment: no unfortunatelu not @MohammedAlhanafi

Comment: You should be getting a warning or error or something are you sure you display_errors is on and error reporting is set to show errors and warning? error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: @Danny I am doing it like that ' error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); '

Comment: Try this: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Have you tried to `foreach(json_encode($return_arr) as $lines)` and then save it line by line? or the `$return_arr` is one element?

Comment: @MohammedAlhanafi I kinda fix that with the file_put_contents just have to create a txt file not json. And just have ti change it to json after that

Comment: @Maria It's a pleasure to help you, just close your question :).

Comment: The probelm is that the JSON format is very poorly-suited to streaming, so virtually all JSON libraries will need to hold the entire raw data set in memory, and then build a *second copy* as the encoded JSON document. The same will apply for *de*coding as well. You can *probably* get away with the hacky "write JSON by hand" method as suggested, so long as you know to escape your data according to the JSON standard, but if these are just rows from a DB result set why not simply write them as CSV which is easily streamed as both input and output, and well-suited to a DB result format?